# Adding a short description to a list name

Tags: trello

Is there a way to add a short description in a list header so users understand exactly what the purpose of a list is?

Comment: It is not possible right now. You can send an email to `feature-ideas@trello.com` to propose this feature.

Comment: This is a "must". I hope trello admins read this site. (and I wrote another email to feature-ideas, as it never hurts to increase the number of requests)

Answer (score 2):

Card lists don't have a separate description, just the title.

However, the title can be quite long, if long enough it will automatically split over multiple lines, expanding the header so it isn't truncated.